# Custom Action execution by feature

Tags: wix, wix3

I wrote a custom action to create a scheduled task after install. 
I do not want the Custom Action to run when the user does not want to create the schedule task. During installation even if I select " Feature will be unAvailable" the schtask is getting created. How do i prevent the Custom Action from executing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set a condition for your CA execution:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="ScheduleTaskCA" After="InstallFinalize">
        <![CDATA[&feature_name=3]]>
    </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Hope it helps.

> If you want to read more about CAs conditions, you can chech the link below.
>   [Advanced Custom Action Conditions](http://www.appdeploy.com/articles/msicustomactions/)

Answer (score 0):

Add  to your Install execute sequence.

Comment: <![CDATA[&SWUSchedTaskFeature=3]]>

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found out the problem. The &FeatureName = 3 tells me that the feature is to be installed, and the opposite to that, is !FeatureName = 3, which means the feature is installed already. This fixed my problem so the final solution became

```
&FeatureName = 3 OR (!FeatureName  = 3 AND NOT (Uninstalling OR MSIPATCHREMOVE OR RemovingForUpgrade)
```

Answer (score 0):

"MyService" is feature Name

"FEATURE_MyService" is my condition Name: I am using checkbox to set the value of FEATURE_MyService property

```
<Control Id="Chk1" Type="CheckBox" Height="12" Width="110" X="50" Y="199" Text="Portal Windows Service" Property="FEATURE_MyService" CheckBoxValue="0" Hidden="yes">

<Custom Action='CAction1' After="InstallExecute">
    NOT Installed AND <![CDATA[(&MyService=3)]]>
```

```
<Custom Action='CAction2' Before='InstallExecute'>
    <![CDATA[(&MyService=3 AND NOT Installed)]]>
```

```
<Custom Action='CAction3' After='InstallFinalize'>
    <![CDATA[FEATURE_MyService AND NOT Installed ]]>
```